# Using Sails.js is it possible to sort with waterline by true/false?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm using Sails.js and thus, Waterline and I'm wondering if the following is possible?

```
teamFind: function(req,res,next){
 User.find().skip(req.param('listPage')).limit(26).sort('school').sort('officialUser').exec(function(err,users){
      res.view({
        teams:users,
        nextPage: parseInt(req.param('listPage'),10)+26
      });
    });
  },
```

What I'm wanting to do is return the users sorted by school and then move the "Official Users" to the top of that list.  Currently this just returns everything in alphabetic order.  Is the issue that 'officialUser' is a boolean?

Comment: I guess in the end the boolean values translate to zeros and ones.. Hence the ones with the false should come first.. Is it the case..??

Comment: You know, it never crossed my mind that it would work that way (false FIRST because it's 0).  I'll give that a try.

Comment: The key was switching the sorts around ('school' last) and changing 'officialUser' to 'officialUser desc'.

Comment: What does sort('school last') do.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was unclear.  I should have said move sort('school') after sort('officialUser desc').

Comment: @gregdillon, glad you figure this out--please post it as an answer (you can post and accept answers to your own question) so that others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The main issue was that I had objects I wanted to sort in the wrong order. Also, I needed to add 'desc' to the 'officialUser' sort.